# Symfony2 - doctrine get tables creation order

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony 2.7, doctrine 2, MySQL.
I'm trying to retrieve the tables creation order in a controller as when issuing

> php app/console doctrine:generate:schema --dump-sql

but I only need the table names.
So, for instance, if I have two tables like
**Product - Category** I'd like to have an output which looks like this : array('Category', 'Product')

Using [this documentation](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html) here's what I've done so far:

```
public function getTablesCreationOrderAction()
{
    $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
    $sm = $conn->getSchemaManager();
    $sequences = $sm->listSequences($this->getParameter('database_name'));
    die();
}
```

An exception is thrown at $sequences = $sm->listSequences.

Here's the exception I get:

> Operation 'Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform::getListSequencesSQL' is not supported by platform.

I don't know if this means that MySQL does not support the operation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, here's how I did it. There may be better ways..

```
public function getTablesCreationOrderAction()
{
    $app = New Application($this->get('kernel'));
    $app->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = New ArrayInput(['command' => 'doctrine:schema:create',
                             '--dump-sql'=>true]);
    $output = New BufferedOutput();

    $app->run($input, $output);
    $rst = $output->fetch();

    $schema = explode('CREATE TABLE ', $rst);

    $tables = [];
    foreach ($schema as $tableDef)
    {
        $tables[] = explode(' (', $tableDef)[0];
    }

    unset($tables[0]); // empty
    var_dump($tables);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it seems like the feature isn't implemented yet, since this is in the source code of [AbstractPlatform](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/AbstractPlatform.php) you will see this:

```
public function getListSequencesSQL($database)
{
    throw DBALException::notSupported(__METHOD__);
}
```

Now this means that platforms overriding `AbstractPlatform` must override these functions to provide the right implementation.
Now if you take a look at [MySqlPlatform](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php), you won't be able to find the `getListSequencesSQL()` anywhere, hence you can't use this feature with `mysql` or at least it's not implemented.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know if there is another way to achieve what I'm looking for?